# How to convert from ModelIO MDLMesh to SceneKit SCNGeometry and back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit, modelio

Apple have recently announced Model I/O Framework and, understandably, documentation is currently [quite sparse](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ModelIO/Reference/ModelIO_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015421) with many classes still not fully documented. The [Model I/O talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=602) suggests a two-way link between SceneKit classes and Model I/O classes, but I can't find a way to do this in practice.

`SCNGeometry` has a `convenience init` which accepts a `MDLMesh` object, but I'm not sure how to go the other way and generate a `MDLMesh` object from a pre-existing `SCNGeometry`.

The `init` for `MDLMesh` is:

```
init(vertexBuffer vertexBuffer: MDLMeshBuffer,
     vertexCount vertexCount: Int,
     descriptor descriptor: MDLVertexDescriptor,
     submeshes submeshes: [MDLSubmesh])
```

or, alternatively, the same but with `vertexBuffers: [MDLMeshBuffer]` (where a vertex buffer corresponds to a SceneKit geometry source), I can't figure out where to go from here.

(It looks like `MDLMeshBuffer` has a method which takes a `fillData: NSData` parameter, and I know `SCNGeometry.geometrySources` gives an array of `SCNGeometrySources` each with a `.data` that provides these geometry sources as an `NSData` object, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about doing it.)

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find out about this bridge?

Comment: Not yet, but I plan to re-visit it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to engineers in the labs at WWDC, the SceneKit to Model I/O bridge isn't in the first beta, but should show up in another beta later in the summer.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the inside info :-) Will look forward to it!